# How to get the value from the formElement:formInputBox in hybris?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

`formElement:formInputBox` is a kind of input field. Suddenly I could not find documentation for them. Aplying an `id` field to them breakes a code. I need to get the value inside the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `idKey` for setting an id? e.g.

```
<formElement:formInputBox idKey="profile.email" labelKey="profile.email" path="email" inputCSS="text" mandatory="true"/>
```

Also, check this file for more information:

- /yacceleratorstorefront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/formElement/formInputBox.tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way.

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="forgottenPwdForm">
        <formElement:formInputBox idKey="forgottenPwd.email" labelKey="forgottenPwd.email" path="email" inputCSS="text" mandatory="true"/>
        <button class="positive" type="submit"><spring:theme code="forgottenPwd.submit"/></button>
    </form:form>
```

To support this you should have formElement.tag [image]